# Remove all occurrences of double quotes from text (python csv)

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, text

I have a text file that I obtained by converting a dataframe using `csv` module in Python as follows:

```
df.to_csv(r'listfinal.txt', header=None, index=None, sep=' ', mode='a')
```

The text file has double quotes around many entries, i.e,

```
Circles "Post Malone"
"You Know You Like It" "DJ Snake"
"Future Nostalgia" "Dua Lipa"
```

I wish to remove all such double quotes from anywhere on this file.
What do I change in the initial conversion `df.to_csv`?

Comment: Use `df = df.replace('"','', regex=True)`

Comment: Or:  `df = df.replace({'"','', "'": ""}, regex=True)`

Comment: @jezrael I do not have the double quotes in the dataframe itself. But they are generated when I convert it to a text file using df.to_csv
I think you misinterpreted the question

Comment: @AmanArora what does it look like before?

Comment: If you remove quotes, how do you distinguish the separators ` ` and the normal spaces ` ` within a cell?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
df.to_csv(r'listfinal.txt', header=None, index=None, sep=' ', mode='a', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

you could also use csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL instead